# Brace from {cases} environment disappears after rowcolors*{1}{...}{...}

Tags: tables, color, braces

I use `rowcolors*{1}{...}{...}` to color a table, then I use it again (with white as arguments) to reset the color. After that, braces look weird (they disappear slightly).

If I use `scrbook`, `book`, `article` (e.g.) the above error occurs.
If I use `minimal`, the brace looks normal.

Why is that, and what can I do to fix the error?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
% rowcolors*{1}{...}{...} ommitted.
% TABLE ommited.
\rowcolors*{1}{white}{white}

\[
x =
\begin{cases}
y & z
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use a group to keep local the effect of `\rowcolors`: `{\rowcolors*{1}{white}{white}\begin{tabular}{...}...\end{tabular}} \[ x= \begin{cases}...\end{cases}\]`. Or is it the equation inside the table?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's one of those undocumented features. This works

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
% rowcolors*{1}{...}{...} ommitted.
% TABLE ommited.
\rowcolors*{1}{white}{white}

\[\csname CT@everycr\endcsname{}
x =
\begin{cases}
y & z
\end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```