# unset rowcolor in eqnarray

Tags: math-mode, rowcolor

I have a document with a defined `\rowcolors`

Now in a math environment, a cases element is rendered with this table background overlapping the brace:

This can be fixed by adding `\rowcolors{1}{}{}`

Unfortunately, this does not work in an eqnarray environment.

has no effect and putting it in the cases statement
only makes both rows with a white background, still overlaying the brace.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, titlepage, german, final]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}      %puts colors in tables

\definecolor{tr_color1}{HTML}{FFFFFF} %Weiß
\definecolor{tr_color2}{HTML}{E5F2FF} %Blau
\rowcolors{1}{tr_color1}{tr_color2}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amstext, amsfonts, mathrsfs} % Mathematische Symbole
\begin{document}
\[
    PD(t)= \begin{cases}
    1 : x \\
    0 : y
    \end{cases}
\]

\[\rowcolors{1}{}{}
    PD(t)= \begin{cases}
    1 : x \\
    0 : y
    \end{cases}
\]

\begin{eqnarray*}
    \rowcolors{}{}{}
    d & = & \begin{cases} 1 : PD(i)=1 \\ 0 : PD(i)=0 \end{cases}\\
    z & = & xx
\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{eqnarray*}
    d & = & \begin{cases}\rowcolors{}{}{} 1 : PD(i)=1 \\ 0 : PD(i)=0 \end{cases}\\
    z & = & xx
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

The tip from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87064/brace-from-cases-environment-disappears-after-rowcolors1) (`\csname CT@everycr\endcsname{}`) does not work either.

So how can I unset the rowcolors inside the eqnarray environmnent?

Comment: Why do you make it so difficult to test your issue? Why don't you show a complete example instead of all this snippets?

Comment: also as you have `cases` you are presumably loading amsmath in which case there really is no use case for using `eqnarray` The main aim of `amsmath` is to provide functional alignments to make up for `eqnarray`'s deficiencies.

Comment: @Ulrike, probably because I missed the part of providing the minimal example doc, sorry

Comment: @David. correct. Which would that be?

Comment: @Jan `align` normally

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work; basically, we nullify the action of `\@rowc@lors` in the `amsmath` alignments. Of course, I do nothing to `eqnarray` that should never be used.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd\env@cases{\def\@rowc@lors{}}{}{}
\pretocmd\start@align{\def\@rowc@lors{}}{}{}
\makeatother

\definecolor{tr_color1}{HTML}{FFFFFF} %Weiß
\definecolor{tr_color2}{HTML}{E5F2FF} %Blau
\rowcolors{1}{tr_color1}{tr_color2}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
a & a \\
b & b \\
c & c
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\[
    PD(t)= \begin{cases}
    1 : x \\
    0 : y
    \end{cases}
\]

\begin{align*}
    d & = \begin{cases} 1 : PD(i)=1 \\ 0 : PD(i)=0 \end{cases}\\
    z & = xx
\end{align*}

\begin{gather*}
a = b \\
c = d
\end{gather*}

\begin{multline*}
a + b \\
c + d
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, I will copy this in my document. Cool for having a central solution. One Question: can you explain or point to explanation of `\pretocmd\env@cases{\def\@rowc@lors{}}{}{}`? I can guess `\pretocmd\env@cases` and `\def` But why these extra `@` and the order of brace-levels?

Comment: @Jan `\@rowc@lors` is the macro that contains the instructions for changing the color after the first row.

Comment: ah, and the `\pretocmd` has three arguments, where the first is set to `\@rowc@lors{}` where the latter two are empty - hence the two pairs of curly braces. Thanks.

Comment: In order to get it finally working, I had to extend the argument in the ``\pretocmd\…{}`` to ``\def\@rowc@lors{\@rowcolors\@empty}``. I could not figure out which of my other usepackages or else could trigger this need. But now it looks as desired.

Answer (score 2):

You can also disable the rowcolors (locally) with `\@rowcolorsfalse` (and with `\everydisplay{\@rowcolorsfalse}` for all display math). But imho the more interesting question is how to color the cases without overwriting the brace. It is not so easy to change the overhang, but this seems to work:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, titlepage, german, final]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}%
\usepackage{multirow}

\definecolor{tr_color1}{HTML}{FFFFFF} %Weiß
\definecolor{tr_color2}{HTML}{E5F2FF} %Blau
\rowcolors{1}{tr_color1}{tr_color2}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox,array}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\[ \@rowcolorsfalse
    PD(t)=
    \begin{cases}
    1 : x \\
    0 : y
    \end{cases}
\]


\[
    PD(t)=
    \begin{cases}
    1 : x \\
    0 : y
    \end{cases}
\]

\patchcmd\env@cases{@{}l}{@{}>{\columncolor{white}[0.2pt][\tabcolsep]}l}{}{}%


\[
    PD(t)= 
    \begin{cases}
    1 : x \\
    0 : y
    \end{cases}
\]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @david-carlisle for the answer. (seems he doesn't need the answer reputation :D)

So far the original question is not answered. But the problem arises in a `\cases`-statement inside an `\eqnarray` where the rowcolor cannot be unset so far.

This can be bypassed by using normal math environment, where rowcolor unset works and using the `aligned`-environment from amsmath-package.

```
\[
    \rowcolors{1}{}{}
    \begin{aligned}
        d & = \begin{cases} 1 : PD(i)=1 \\ 0 : PD(i)=0 \end{cases}\\
        z & = xx
    \end{aligned}
\]
```

I leave that open in case some can answer the actual question too.